# Print the "title" variable in unformatted views twig

Tags: views

I am trying to do something like this in views-view-unformatted-something.html.twig:

```
<h3 class="{{ title }}">{{ title }}</h3>
```

...but something goes wrong. Nothing is injected into the class.

Comment: `Nothing is injected into the class` likely because `{{ title }}` has some markup like `<div class="view-title">My Cool Title</div>` and it's not just the raw value of `My Cool Title`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using .addClass -> https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates

```
  <h3 {{title_attributes.addClass(title)}}>{{ title }}</h3>
```

Additionally, if you are attempting to access the title of the page, which I assume you are, you may have better luck overriding 'page-title.html.twig' instead, since that is actually what renders the title element (your results may vary).

[image]

[image: worked for me]